# Big Query data changes format when exported to Google Sheets

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this database where I export **ItemIDBundle** that consists of a string Array:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG1Wf.png

When I run the query, the ItemIDBundle displays the data normally, each id separated by a comma.
When I export to CSV or google sheets, the format for some of the entries gets broken, while some remain well-formatted:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbM3z.png

Does anyone know how I can fix this? I tried changing the cell format on google sheets but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's a pain when this happens, spreadsheets like to remove leading zeros and when you have two IDs together seperated by one comma it's identifying this as a number.

I'd suggest using a different delimiter in between your itemids, such as a pipe (|).

For me this works in Google sheets.

```
with itemids as (
select "0000000003,0000000288" as ids
)

select replace(ids,","," | ") from itemids
```